# How to not repeat myself in this situation? C functions that are the same but have different arguments

Tags: c, struct

Now I know what you are thinking - the thing that I described in the title sounds just like overloading. I know that is not a thing in C and I'm not going for it anyways. I have these 2 functions - ABSOLUTELY the same in their body, but the arguments are 2 different structs. Basically it's a binary search tree struct and a red black tree struct. As you may know the structs have only one difference - the red black tree struct contains one more field and that's the color one. Also the functions search, min, max, predecessor, successor.. those are going to have the EXACT same body but alas they take 2 different types of structs. And of course the insert and delete methods will be different.

So I was thinking how can I avoid breaking the number one rule in programming and not repeat myself? I thought about a lot of solutions but none work when I try to find a way to implement it. I thought about just using one function for both but I can't do that since the structs are different. I thought about using macros but honestly I have no idea how to make those work and I am not even sure that they can avoid the problem that I have 2 different structs. I thought about making one generic struct and have the rb struct contain it and a color variable but this straight up changes the code with a few characters everywhere since I have to go one level deeper into the struct to get the values and I no longer have duplicate code.

Just an example of what the problem looks like:

```
bst_search(bstTree t, char *k)
{
    // Searching in tree
}

rb_search(rbTree t, char *k)
{
    // SAME code for searching in tree
}
```

If I was coding in java I would probably solve this using an abstract superclass but C doesn't have fancy stuff like that.

Some extra info: both implementations have their own header and class files and I'd like to keep it that way. Right now I have duplicate code all over those 2 classes and the only things differing are the names of the functions and the structs (except for the insert and delete functions ofc).

Sorry if this has an obvious solution I just don't find a way out of this without duplicating my code.

Comment: If you don't want to change all the rest of the code by having a generic struct, do it in each of two calling functions (one for each type). Copy the relevant members to your common struct, and call the search function.

Comment: The number one rule is certainly not DRY. I would put KISS first. But, of course, you get a different answer what the first rule should be for every programmer you ask...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the `rbTree` with a `bstTree` as the first member thus:

```
typedef struct
{
   bstTree common ;
   int color ;
} rbTree
```

Then you can safely cast an `rbTree` to a `bstTree`, so `rb_search()` can be implemented as a simple macro thus:

```
#define rb_search(t, k) bst_search( (bstTree*)(t). k )
```

One problem is that now for any code that is unique to `rbTree` you have to access most of the members via teh `common` member.  That however is not entirely necessary; if you do not define `rbTree` with a `bstTree` member, but simply ensure that both are defined identically with the common members first and in the same order and type, you will be able to cast one to the other and access the members so long as the same packing and alignment options are applied to all modules that use the structures - doing that however is far less safe and less easily maintained.  A somewhat ugly but safer way to do this is to place the common members in an include file and `#include` the members in each struct definition.

Comment: Best answer. This is how Windows API handles new versions of old structures.

Comment: I would always define that macro like this: `#define rb_search(t, k) bst_search(&(t)->common, k)` That way you retain type checking on its invocations, making the compiler scream if you call it with `rb_search(hashTablePointer, "foo")`.

Comment: I like this version but when I started implementing it I remembered - the generic bstTree has 3 pointers - parent, right and left and they are all bstTree pointers. So if I have a rbTree containing a bstTree which contains pointers to other bstTrees there is no connection between rbTree nodes. Which kinda beats the purpose of a tree. Is there any workaround to this that doesn't involve more code duplication? Should I just go ahead and do the same code for every different tree?

Comment: @user3212138 :  The original premise was that the structures differed in only one member - now there are four!  I cannot help it if the original question is inaccurate.  Perhaps you should have included the definitions and the code so as not to rely on clairvoyance!

Comment: @Clifford Yeah, sorry I was celebrating the holidays and didn't have access to my code. I still don't have it on this laptop but I'm pretty sure it goes like this - http://pastebin.com/9sK3GV6C .Thing is I have them wrapped in dictionary structs as well to encapsulate the data.
Once again I'm sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: @user3212138 :  No problem.  At this point I'd be saying to myself - "*Ah!  that's what C++ is for!*" - light bulb moment. ;-)

Comment: @Clifford Exactly what I thought! I was like *"Oh man I could use some of that java magic right now.."*. It's good to see someone else say that there isn't a pretty way to do it in C. I'll just leave it as that because I really don't feel like creating complicated code to solve something so simple and trivial. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way of doing it in C (in contrast to C++ where templates exist for exactly this purpose).

Ugly way #1. By using macro:

```
#define MAKE_SEARCH_FUNCTION(FN_NAME, VAR_TYPE) \
FN_NAME(VAR_TYPE t, char *k) \
{ \
    /* Searching in tree */ \
}

struct bstTree {
};
MAKE_SEARCH_FUNCTION(bst_search, struct bstTree*)

struct rbTree {
};
MAKE_SEARCH_FUNCTION(rb_search, struct rbTree*)
```

Ugly way #2. By moving body into separate include file. A bit more work, but makes sense if function is very large or if you need to generate whole families of functions at once (e.g. `bst_search()`/`bst_add()`/ `bst_remove()`).

// header.h

```
FN_NAME(VAR_TYPE t, char *k) 
{
    // Searching in tree
}
```

// source.c

```
struct bstTree {
};
#define VAR_TYPE struct bstTree*
#define FN_NAME bst_search
#include "header.h"
#undef VAR_TYPE
#undef FN_NAME

struct rbTree {
};
#define VAR_TYPE struct rbTree*
#define FN_NAME rb_search
#include "header.h"
#undef VAR_TYPE
#undef FN_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

A macro that acted on a generic input tree would make it, but I find that solution somehow dirty.

Another approach is to have a generic struct with all the members of both trees together, without nested structs. For example:

```
struct genericTree {
  // common members for both trees 
 ... 
  // members for rb trees 
 ... 
  // members for bst
 ... 
}
```

Then you have a single function:

```
search(genericTree* t, char* k)
```

To keep the semantics, use typedefs:

```
typedef genericTree bstTree;
typedef genericTree rbTree;
```

So you can still have functions that get a bstTree or a rbTree when they expect only one if those types.

The drawback of this approach is that you take more memory for a single tree because you keep members of the other. You may ease it with some unions, probably.